# Programatically press on the emoji button in EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to show an emoji only keyboard, but all the libraries I came across use libraries with resources that are used as emoji's, or just extremely complex solutions. My goal is to show emoji's only in the keyboard in an `EditText` or Jetpack compose solution.

I was wondering if I can programatically click on the Emoji button, that would work for me as well, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Tried looking around but found nothing, interesting question

Comment: I believe it's impossible because not all keyboards are even guaranteed to have an emoji page. I'm not entirely sure though.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if I can programatically click on the Emoji button

No.

There is no requirement for a keyboard to offer an emoji button. Those that do are not required to have it at any given place. And, keyboards are a separate app, and you cannot inject UI events like clicks into other apps, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard API to do that, in fact there's no requirement for a keyboard to include emojis either and, even then, how would that guarantee that the every user gets a uniform experience?

You could instruct the user to install a separate keyboard you link to, but that would drive off many users.

You need to **provide one inside the app**, by building one yourself, or using an existing library.